# What is the proper isolation level needed in this postgres query with concurrent transaction?

Tags: postgresql

I have 2 concurrent transactions

on table X with the following column

```
id
count
```

and

table Y with the following column

```
id
somefield
```

currently there is only 1 row in tableX

```
id=1
count=0
```

and a million row in tableY

transaction 1

```
Begin
     select * where id = 1 from tableX
     select count(*) from tableY
     update set count = count + 1 from tableX
END
```

transaction 2

```
Begin
     select * where id = 1 from tableX
     select count(*) from tableY
     update set count = count + 1 from tableX
END
```

If isolation level is REPEATABLE READ , postgres will snapshot id=1

and the result of both transaction will be count=1 instead of count=2

Should i use SERIALIZABLE isolation to lock the row instead? But if I use SERIALIZABLE isolation it locks the entire tableY will millions of row

is there more fine grain lock available in postgres?

Answer (score 0):

> If isolation level is REPEATABLE READ , postgres will snapshot id=1 and the result of both transaction will be count=1 instead of count=2

That is bit unclear how did you come to such conclusion and whether you have checked that or not. The phenomenon, you are asking about, is actually called [(P4) Lost Update](https://arxiv.org/pdf/cs/0701157.pdf) and it is forbidden in RR isolation level, regardless how you perform updates:

```
-- tx1
tx1=> begin transaction isolation level repeatable read;
BEGIN
tx1=*> update c set count=1 where id=1;
UPDATE 1
tx1=*>

-- tx2
tx2=> begin transaction isolation level repeatable read;
BEGIN
tx2=*> update c set count=2 where id=1;
... WAITING ...

-- tx1
tx1=*> commit;
COMMIT
tx1=> select * from c;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     1
(1 row)

-- tx2
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
tx2=!> rollback;
ROLLBACK
```

OR

```
-- tx1
tx1=> begin transaction isolation level repeatable read;
BEGIN
tx1=*> update c set count=count+1 where id=1;
UPDATE 1
tx1=*>

-- tx2
tx2=> begin transaction isolation level repeatable read;
BEGIN
tx2=*> update c set count=count+1 where id=1;
... WAITING ...

-- tx1
tx1=*> commit;
COMMIT

-- tx2
ERROR:  could not serialize access due to concurrent update
tx2=!> rollback;
ROLLBACK
```

The actual purpose of your `update` statement, based on DB state (someones call it `atomic update` or `atomic write`), is to maintain consistent state in DB even using RC isolation level:

```
-- tx1
tx1=> begin;                            
BEGIN
tx1=*> select * from c;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     3
(1 row)

tx1=*> update c set count=count+1 where id=1;
UPDATE 1
tx1=*> select * from c;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     4
(1 row)

-- tx2
tx2=> begin; 
BEGIN
tx2=*> select * from c;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     3
(1 row)

tx2=*> update c set count=count+1 where id=1;
... WATING ...

-- tx1
tx1=*> commit;
COMMIT

-- tx2
UPDATE 1
tx2=*> select * from c;
 id | count 
----+-------
  1 |     5
(1 row)

tx2=*> commit;
COMMIT
```